# SQL: Find closest number to given value with ties

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to find the closest number(s) to a given value in SQL. I have already made my query for multiple results:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars
ORDER BY ABS(price - $price)
```

I know I can limit the table by using LIMIT 1, by which I have one number closest to the given value. But how can I include ties? Like for example when there are three or four cars with the same price? The amount of cars which have the same price is dynamic, so I can't specify a certain LIMIT.

I also know I could use `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES`, but I can't use this query because my database driver doesn't allow it. Does anybody have another idea of how to accomplish this?

Example:

- car 1 = 2000
- car 2 = 3000
- car 3 = 3000
- car 4 = 1500

When I want the cars closest to 3000, the query should return:

- car 2
- car 3

But without using a static LIMIT in the query, because the amount of cars with the same price can be different every time. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your driver supports nested queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CARS 
WHERE ABS(price - $price) = ( SELECT MIN(ABS(price - $price)) FROM CARS )
```

Comment: Awesome man, that did the trick! Can't believe it's so easy. Cheers

Comment: Technically that does not match the full question asked, that will only return the value if they enter the Exact value that matches the table, but not the "closest" value, I.e. if 2999 was entered, no results would return.